# Por que é chamado de método estático os métodos sem estado? (c#)

Tags: c#, ciência-da-computação

Se a definição de um método estático é poder ser acessado sem a variável de uma instância, poder ser acessado diretamente, e o estado do programa é a coleção dos valores armazenados na memória, descrevendo a condição do ambiente de execução, por que os chamam de métodos estáticos? Qual a relação dos dois conceitos

Comment: *"Se a definição de..."* olá, pode citar as fontes dessas definições? talvez lendo melhor até tenha uma resposta para isso

Comment: Essa definição "...a definição de um método estático é poder ser acessado sem a variável de uma instância..." não é correta. Em C# método estático é aquele método cujo a cópia é mantida a nível de classe e não a nível de instancia.

Comment: Eu achei essa explicação para a origem do nome, porém não consegui localizar o autor portanto então só posso deixar como comentário mesmo. Segue a suposição etimológica: *Métodos estáticos são chamados de "estáticos" porque são resolvidos em tempo de compilação com base na classe em que são chamados e não dinamicamente como no caso de métodos de instância, que são resolvidos polimorficamente com base no tipo de Objeto em tempo execução.*

Comment: Não acredito que seja por isso. Quando o tipo do objeto é perfeitamente conhecido, métodos de instância (e mesmo métodos marcados como virtuais) também podem ser resolvidos "estaticamente", sem acessar uma vtable.

Answer (score -2):

Acredito que no C++ eles reciclaram a palavra-chave `static` do C para esse tipo de método, e o apelido acabou pegando.

Comment: kcete, 6 falam grego, não intendi nada, podem abaixar um pouco o nivl?